# Reference for Turan Density

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I am working a 3-graph problem. I convert it to calculate Turan density, that is $lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{ex_3(n,F)}{\binom{n}{3}}$, where F is a3-graph. I'd like to know are there some methods and classic papers in this area?

Comment: This is a rather broad question.  We are very bad at calculating Turán densities, with exact answers known for very few $F$.  It might help to know a little bit about the $F$ you are interested in.

Comment: @BenBarber I'm interested in tight cycles, expansion of stars and the 3-graphs viewing triangles of wheels as edges.

Answer (score 2):

In his 2011 paper Peter Keevash surveys the known results and methods, and discusses some open problems: [Hypergraph Turán problems](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~keevash/papers/turan-survey.pdf), Surveys in combinatorics 392 (2011): 83-140.

In particular, you might want to look at flag algebras. See, for instance

Falgas-Ravry, V., & Vaughan, E. R. (2013). Applications of the semi-definite method to the Turán density problem for 3-graphs. Combinatorics, Probability and Computing, 22(01), 21-54, [doi:10.1017/S0963548312000508](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0963548312000508)

Razborov, A. A. (2013). [Flag algebras: an interim report.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-7254-4_16) In The Mathematics of Paul Erdős II (pp. 207-232).